# How can I test if a client-server program supports multiple clients?

Tags: java, sockets

I have written a client-server program that in theory should support multiple clients, however, I am having trouble testing it.
Inputs are via the Eclipse IDE console, I copied the client code while changing the class name and trying to run both on different windows while the server is listening, they connected successfully but I am having an issue: both consoles display the same outputs, so, for example, I can input anything from either console but when I do it, both the input and output would have been the same in the other console without me doing anything

I have thought about doing this via the command line but changing all my inputs into command-line arguments will take a lot of time as it is a big code with many inputs, is there any other way to do it

Comment: Without seeing code its hard to tell much, but one of the reason that both consoles are showing same results is because both clients are handled by the server on same socket